# How to assemble a URL back to the www route when inside a Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname route?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I have spent hours trying to find a solution to this but doesn't appear to be much out there.

I currently have `admin.domain.com` point to the admin module which is easy to do like so:

```
$adminRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
        'admin.domain.com', array(
            'module' => 'admin'
        )
    );
$router
    ->addRoute('admin', $adminRoute->chain(
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':controller/:action/*',
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            ))
    ));
```

And all other routes will work as per the default routing so that `www.domain.com/module/controller` and `www.domain.com/controller` both work as expected.

However, if I am currently inside the `admin` module and want to assemble a URL which points back to the `www.domain.com` route, then how does one do this?

Unfortunately it's not a simple case of making the default route a Hostname route for `www.domain.com` because then you don't benefit from the 'optional' module param in the path. E.g.

```
    $wwwRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
        'www.domain.com', array(
            'module' => 'default'
        )
    );
$router
    ->addRoute('default', $wwwRoute->chain(
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            ':module/:controller/:action/*',
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            ))
    ));
```

Will simply build all paths in the format `www.domain.com/default/controller/action` rather than `www.domain.com/controller/action`

The docs suggest that the default routing uses `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module` but i've tried that and it seems there's more to than just that.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm suspecting that you either need to do one way or the other i.e. have all modules on a subdomain and then route the requests strictly like so `/controller/action/*`, or, have modules as part of the route path. Otherwise, a module would be reachable via two URLs - `module.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/module` - obviously there are ways round this, and of course, you could just set up specific routes for each module thereby not relying on the 'optional' module feature of the default Zend routing.